# I get an error installing Xdebug on Alpine docker. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, docker, xdebug, alpine-linux, pecl

I'm trying to install Xdebug on Alpine 3.17, but the different solutions I found with Google didn't work out. I'm a bit lost on this.

I try to use PECL to install Xdebug as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/15828211b562d617ad16fdb866b6fdc800c95c34/php#pecl-extensions).

But I only get the message:

```bash
#7 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
------
 > [ 3/34] RUN pecl install xdebug:
#7 0.416 /bin/sh: pecl: not found
------
Dockerfile:30
--------------------
  28 |         composer
  29 |     
  30 | >>> RUN pecl install xdebug
  31 |     RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
  32 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.17

RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    tzdata \
    bash \
    vim \
    supervisor \
    nginx \
    nginx-mod-http-headers-more \
    gcc \
    musl-dev \
    php81 \
    php81-phar \
    php81-fpm \
    php81-curl \
    php81-redis \
    php81-opcache \
    php81-mysqlnd \
    php81-pdo_mysql \
    php81-tokenizer \
    php81-dom \
    php81-fileinfo \
    php81-xml \
    php81-xmlwriter \
    php81-xmlreader \
    composer

RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime

RUN mkdir /etc/supervisor.d
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/snippets
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN mkdir /run/php
RUN mkdir /srv/ylvi

COPY docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY docker/supervisor-php-fpm81.ini /etc/supervisor.d/php-fpm81.ini
COPY docker/supervisor-nginx.ini /etc/supervisor.d/nginx.ini
COPY docker/supervisor-cron.ini /etc/supervisor.d/cron.ini
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/nginx-mo.conf /etc/nginx/snippets/mo.conf
COPY docker/nginx-fastcgi-php.conf /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf
COPY docker/nginx-php8.1-fpm.conf /etc/nginx/snippets/php8.1-fpm.conf
COPY docker/nginx-chk.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/nginx-chk.conf
COPY docker/nginx-ylvi.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/ylvi.conf
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf
COPY docker/health_check.php /var/www/localhost/htdocs/health_check.php
COPY docker/php-mo.ini /etc/php81/conf.d/99_mo.ini
COPY docker/php-fpm.conf /etc/php81/php-fpm.conf
COPY docker/php-www.conf /etc/php81/php-fpm.d/www.conf

WORKDIR /srv/www
RUN /bin/touch storage/logs/laravel.log
RUN /bin/chown nginx:nginx -R /srv/ylvi

# Add the cron job
RUN crontab -l | { cat; cat docker/crontab.conf; } | crontab -

EXPOSE 10080

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

I already tried to add `$PHPIZE_DEPS`, or use `php8.1-pecl-xdebug` instead of `PECL install`. Also as you can see I added `musl-dev` and `gcc` to apk add but to no avail. Also I found, that there are more people having issues with PECL under Alpine (https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1134), but that doesn't seem like my problem.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why are your reinventing the wheel instead of using the existing `php:8.1-alpine3.17` image? If you look at the code for the said image, you’ll see they are compiling PHP from sources with specific comments pointed at the fact it looks to be the only way to make PECL work: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/5bfc95d4880599cf9e85f5b5f99940cf123ebcf0/8.1/alpine3.17/zts/Dockerfile#L156

Comment: The truth is, its because we wanted nearly the same configuration like other older servers we use, but administrator is not available right now, so i am a bit struggling. I now tried to use the suggested image `php:8.1-alpine3.17`, but to no avail. I don't get an error anymore on the installation, but its not available afterwards. A `php -v` doesn't print out its existence.

Comment: Most probably because the container will add it to the ini that is serving web request not the CLI

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in: **#7 0.416 /bin/sh: pecl: not found**.

If you want to use `pecl`, you need to install `php81-pear` with `apk`, but in general, you shouldn't compile your own extensions when packages, such as `php81-pecl-xdebug` are already available.

You didn't say why installing *that* one did not work though.

Comment: I tried that too but got `unknown instruction: docker-php-ext-enable` for xdebug. I made many different tryouts and cant tell anymore what exactly was the problem with that one. Currently i'm stuck at this `/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install xdebug did not complete successfully: exit code: 127`